# Wordpress search results by keyword

Tags: wordpress, search, keyword, relevanssi

Is there a way to prioritise the search results by keywords or tags.
For example, if a user types in Admissions then domain/admissions page comes first and then all the rest. If the word is apply then domain/apply page is first on the search result page and etc
Was trying to find the examples, but no luck. Never used the extended search before, so even don't know where to dig

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about here is returning search results by "relevance" and there are a few examples out there including plugins such as Relevanssi.

I have no example of how to do this, however, I thought it might be useful to know the term you need to dig deeper.